# Laravel Storage:Link not working for custom folder structure

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, symlink, laravel-5.5

My Laravel folder structure is

```
Laravel
|
|--site
|--files
```

Here, **sites** is my **public** folder. And rest of the folders go to **files** folder.

Now, when I run the command `php artisan storage:link`, it says

`System cannot find the path specified`

And obviously, the link is not working.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to update your helper functions

1. public_path()
2. storage_path()

according you your new directory structure

don't change the core may be you can create a new helper file and include in the composer.json.

Comment: Not working. Can you please give some more detailed instruction

Comment: are you handling all of your assets and public paths manually now ?

Comment: add a helper file under any directory lets say, you set a Helpers folder in files and created a helper file in there, then in your composer.json update your autoload object like this.

`"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "files": ["files/Helpers/helpers.php"],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },`

Comment: inside helper.php file write this function

`function public_path($path = '')
    {
        return app()->make('path.site').($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }`

Comment: and for storage path

`function storage_path($path = '')
    {
        return app('path.files.storage').($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
    }`

Comment: public path will now point to host/site/
storage path will now point to host/files/storage